# Mail server and web server on different servers

Tags: linux, php, email, web, host

I am writing a PHP application for a client who currently hosts their website on a shared domain with fasthosts.

The PHP application is going to be stored on a dedicated server at our location. Part of the PHP application is sending bulk emails, so I am going to set up a mail server on this dedicated server.

I have not done much with email servers before, so my question is this. Would using the email server on the dedicated server to send emails from their company domain, a domain which is pointed to the website on the shared fasthosts server, cause any problems? Is there anything I have to bare in mind when setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Yes, it can if they have configured their domain securely.  I find automated e-mail systems tend to be poorly configured.  Spend the time getting it right if you do go this way.

If you do, get your server listed in their [SPF record](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/securing-your-email-reputation-with-spf/).  It is not necessary for your server to use one of their domains.  You just don't want to look like you are [forging their identity](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/detecting-email-server-forgery/).  Setup your server correctly, and you shouldn't have a problem.

One technique that is used in cases like this is to send from a domain you control like "client.example.com".  You just have to be careful not to look like you are phishing.  You can use "Reply-to:" to have replies go to the client.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the receiving server and how it is determining legitimate emails versus spam. Setting up SPF (if not already in place) and including your application server can help. Updating your application to also "SMTP announce" with the client's domain can also help as well.